# Who is Stephen Strange in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, captain-america-the-winter-soldier, doctor-strange

In the discussion of Zola's Algorithm, Agent Sitwell specifically mentions Bruce Banner and Stephen Strange as persons of interest.  Obviously Cap knows Bruce Banner, and (a good portion of) the fanbase knows who Stephen Strange is: the guy who eventually becomes Dr. Strange, Sorcerer Supreme.  Soon after this, it was officially announced that there was a Dr. Strange movie in the works as part of Phase 3 of the Marvel Cinematic Universe.

Since the Dr. Strange movie will (presumably) take place after the events of *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*, the hero Dr. Strange, Sorcerer Supreme does not exist yet.  And yet Agent Sitwell name-drops the guy right alongside one of Captain America's companions, like he's someone Captain America (or possibly The Falcon) should know by name.

Is there any reason why they should?  Who is Stephen Strange before he becomes a superhero?

Comment: A prominent doctor?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if they made him a tv medical celebrity, like Dr Oz.

Comment: They probably just saw his name and thought “Hmmm, something about this guy seems unusual. Odd. Out-of-the-ordinary. Different. Curious. Peculiar. Weird. Irregular. Uncommon. We should keep an eye on him. (Also several huge airborne guns.)”

Comment: Related: [When is Doctor Strange actually set?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62872/49)

Answer (score 21):

As implied by the scene, at the time of *TWS*, he really is just a person with the potential to become a threat to Hydra later on.

Kevin Feige recently [confirmed this](http://comicbook.com/2016/09/27/details-behind-doctor-stranges-captain-america-winter-soldier-ea):

> "He is very well-known as a surgeon," Feige said during a recent visit to the set of Doctor Strange. "He has got various awards and plaques you're going to see over there; he attends various galas, might be driving at one point in this movie. He has name recognition and a talent and certain Hydra computers identified him as somebody that could cause trouble for their agendas."

Comment: Turns out this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 17):

It's been widely reported that Ant-Man will be Marvel's last "origin story," with all future franchises starting with their heroes fully-developed. In fact, this was reported [with specific mention of the Doctor Strange movie](http://www.latino-review.com/news/marvel-no-more-origin-stories-starting-with-doctor-strange):

> "Marvel's new thing is no more origin stories. So Doctor Strange's movie no longer has an origin. It begins *in media res*. It's got Doctor Strange all ready [sic] established as The Sorcerer Supreme. It's a totally new script [...] without any of the previous stuff. They're not even touching the previous script."

So presumably by the time of *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*, Stephen Strange has ALREADY become "Doctor Strange, Sorcerer Supreme," and thus is on Hydra's radar.

As for why Sitwell would mention him specifically: given Captain America's position as a high-ranking SHIELD agent (and presumably a specialist in "enhanced people"), along with Black Widow's position as "that SHIELD chick who knows everything anyway", it would make sense that one or both of them would have been briefed on a living sorcerer, and thus would recognize the name.

Comment: and, to be fair, Ant-Man's Scott Lang's origin story: from what we know, Hank Pym has already been Ant-Man by the time the movie starts.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Good point.

Comment: I'm just happy they've finished origin stories. Man I hate them. First 1/4 of the movie is always crap.

Comment: [This interview](http://www.craveonline.co.uk/entertainment/film/interviews/670837-kevin-feige-interview-captain-america-the-avengers-2-and-dr-strange) with Kevin Fiege has him talking about the way that Zola's algorithm works, and why his name appearing does not necessarily mean he is already "powered".

Comment: @DrRDizzle Right, it's a predictive algorithm, but that doesn't explain why he would MENTION him.  If Strange was still some random surgeon, Sitwell probably wouldn't even remember his name (aside from the fact that it's a funny name), let alone mention it in the same breath as "Bruce Banner."  There's clearly *something* special about Strange at that point, and probably some reason why Cap, Widow, or Falcon would recognize the name.  Otherwise, why bring him up?  What are the odds that the random guy Sitwell happened to mention would become an Avenger, if he wasn't already special somehow?

Comment: @Nerrolken I can't find a reference for it now, but I am *certain* that he is name dropped by Agent Fitz on *Agents of SHIELD* in the first season too. Just because Zola's algorithm had him as a threat - maybe even a substantial one - doesn't mean he is powered. There clearly is SOMETHING special about him, otherwise he wouldn't have been mentioned by both Fitz and Sitwell, but we might not know exactly what until the release of *Dr. Strange*

Comment: “Doctor Strange's movie no longer has an origin. It begins in media res. It's got Doctor Strange all ready [sic] established as The Sorcerer Supreme. It's a totally new script [...] without any of the previous stuff.” — Guess they wrote an even newer script before they started filming!

Comment: This appears to have been wrong

Comment: I've only seen the movie once so far, but is there anything in it to establish the time of events as pre or post Winter Soldier? I don't recall anything in it which does so, though the mention of the Avengers makes it clearly occur after New York. So, while the movie DOES end up being an origin story, it might have occured pre-Winter Soldier and thus SHIELD/Hydra would have learned about him. Other than that, he does demonstrate that he is a genius with a photographic memory, so that alone would make him a threat, though likely not one to be called out in WS.

Answer (score 3):

Although he may not yet be The Sorcerer Supreme, Dr. Stephen Strange is a very highly-skilled surgeon in almost every incarnation of the character, therefore making it very likely that his name would be known not only to S.H.I.E.L.D., but the public in general. Also, S.H.I.E.L.D. would probably have massive interests in a guy willing to travel all the way to Tibet for 'treatment' (I put treatment in parentheses due to S.H.I.E.L.D.'s massive trust issues).

Comment: I'm not sure about that, though.  Off the top of my head, I can't think of any famous modern-day surgeons I could name, except Dr. Oz.  (I didn't think he was actually a doctor, but I just looked him up and apparently he is a genuine surgeon. But either way, practicing surgery is not what he's famous for.)

Comment: I think the larger issue is, why would Sitwell mention him if he was just some doctor?  He mentioned *two people* in the entire world by name, and one of them was an Avenger.  The other MUST have been special for some reason.