# Why did Hydra want to kill Doctor Strange?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange

Based on *The Winter Soldier*, we know that Doctor Strange is on Hydra's list of potential enemies.  Do we know why he was on that list?

Comment: That was not James Rhodes: http://www.digitalspy.com/movies/doctor-strange/news/a812436/where-does-doctor-strange-fit-in-the-mcu-timeline/

Comment: Then why throw out that blatant an Easter Egg? We know the year is 2016, unless the editors screwed up based on awards in his apartment. At the minimum it has to be after the Avengers are formed and known.

Comment: Don't know.  But here's a good answer as well: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/144264/14710

Comment: @phantom42 I do not believe they are duplicates.  The other question has no accepted answers, was asked at a time when the movie was going to be something completely different, and does not ask why Hydra cares about Dr. Strange, but whether the Avengers would know who he is.

Comment: Did you look at the proposed duplicate? It asks why Sitwell, a member of HYDRA would namedrop Stephen Strange. Answers do not need to be accepted for dupes to apply, and the answer on this one is identical to my answer on the previous one.

Comment: @phantom42 I did, and read the answers (and noticed that you gave the same answer he did).  But the other question is not asking why Hydra cares about Stephen Strange, but why Cap and/or Falcon would know him

Comment: Well, feel free to vote to leave it open if you like - but in my mind asking who Strange is, and why Agent Sitwell, an agent of HYDRA would namedrop him when listing threats targeted for death by HYDRA, is the same exact thing as asking why HYDRA would want to kill Strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Surgical talent, basically

Marvel Studios President Kevin Feige was asked about this during a visit to the *Doctor Strange* set; [ComicBookMovie.com reports](https://www.comicbookmovie.com/doctor_strange/kevin-feige-explains-the-doctor-strange-easter-egg-in-captain-a145477) on his response (emphasis mine):

> "He is very well-known as a surgeon," Feige said "He has got various awards and plaques you're going to see over there; he attends various galas, might be driving at one point in this movie. **He has name recognition and a talent and certain Hydra computers identified him as somebody that could cause trouble for their agendas**."