# Was Obidiah Stane with HYDRA?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, iron-man-2008

There were a few moments in *Iron Man* where Obidiah mentions something like

> "bringing the balance of power back in our hands"

and he ordered an assassination attempt on Tony. **Was Stane part of HYDRA?**

Comment: are you sure that this is not 2 questions? (not sure about zolas algorithm there being related enough to be put into one and the same question as the other part)

Comment: Second part of question was an unrelated (and probably unanswerable) question. I've edited it out.

Comment: As far as I can tell he wasn't. Also, why would Hydra want to kill Tony, when at this point he wasn't working for SHIELD...

Comment: This was a theory floating around in 2014, but there's no evidence favoring it within the movies.

Comment: [Stephen Strange was nothing but a talented surgeon](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/141763/5184), but HYDRA wanted him killed because he might cause trouble later. You don't think HYDRA might want a person like Tony eliminated?

Comment: I think the "want him dead" is about either the algo being very good or just being crap.  Given how terrible the US government is at using SIGINT to track terrorists who don't use SIG, I would imagine that Hydra, even if led by absolute screaming (but evil) genius, wouldn't be much better, but would have much much more collateral damage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't any known links between Obadiah Stone and HYDRA, but Stone is known to have business relations with the Ten Rings, which is the villainous group in Iron Man.